# Не могу отобразить поля DateTime

Tags: django, django-admin

Имеется модель

```
class BotUser(models.Model):
    date_in = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)
```

Раньше там стояло значение `auto_now=True` и `auto_now_add=True`
Сейчас потребовалось отобразить их в админ панели для ручной настройки, решил изменить значения на False. Но они все равно не появляются, как быть?

Comment: admin.py для этой модели в студию

Comment: @andreymal `admin.site.register(BotUser)`

Comment: Тогда странненько, сервер был перезапущен после изменений?

Comment: @andreymal да, перезапускал

Comment: @andreymal пробовал еще `date.editable=True`. Не помогло

Comment: Ну фиг знает, у меня такие же поля прекрасно отображаются

Comment: @andreymal только при создании нового поля отображаются, а те что были, не хочет. Но да ладно, хотяб так решил)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Побробуй удалить **auto_now=False**:

```
class BotUser(models.Model):
    date_in = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```